# Add to favorite using room Database

Tags: java, android, android-room, favorites, room

I'm referring this tutorial ==> https://uniqueandrocode.com/add-to-favourites-and-display-favourites-in-recyclerview/ in my project I have bottom navigation...I am trying to add favourites in the first tab and displaying favourites in the second tab in the bottom navigation bar. I'm using Room library.

When activity loads favourites are all blank at first, but when I first row as favourite and go-to favourite tab it displays properly but when I came back to the first tab it fills all the favourites icon automatically (which I have not done I had only done the first row)

Really need help. Thanks in advance.

Dao:

```
    @Dao
    public interface FavoriteDao {

    @Insert
    public void addData(FavoriteList favoriteList);

    @Query("select * from favoritelist")
    public List<FavoriteList> getFavoriteData();

    @Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM favoritelist WHERE id=:id)")
    public int isFavorite(int id);

    @Delete
    public void delete(FavoriteList favoriteList);

   }
```

Database:

```
    @Database(entities={FavoriteList.class},version = 1)
    public abstract class FavoriteDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract FavoriteDao favoriteDao();
    }
```

FavoriteList:

```
    @Entity(tableName="favoritelist")
     public class FavoriteList {


    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "source")
    private String source;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    private String title;


    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    private String url;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "urlToImage")
    private String urlToImage;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "publishedAt")
    private String publishedAt;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrlToImage() {
        return urlToImage;
    }

    public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
        this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
    }

    public String getPublishedAt() {
        return publishedAt;
    }

    public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }
}
```

News fragment:

```
    public class news extends Fragment {
    ImageView favbtn;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    EditText etQuery;
    Button btnSearch;
   
    Adapter adapter;
    List<Articles> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    public static FavoriteDatabase favoriteDatabase;


    public news() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swiprefresh);
        etQuery = view.findViewById(R.id.etQuery);
        btnSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

        favoriteDatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(getActivity(),FavoriteDatabase.class,"myfavdb").
                allowMainThreadQueries().build();


        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        final String country = getCountry();

        retrieveJson("", country, API_Key);

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!etQuery.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            retrieveJson(etQuery.getText().toString(), country, API_Key);
                        }
                    });
                    retrieveJson(etQuery.getText().toString(), country, API_Key);
                } else {

                    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            retrieveJson("", country, API_Key);
                        }
                    });
                    retrieveJson("", country, API_Key);

                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void showChangeLanguageDialog() {

    }

    public void retrieveJson(String query, String country, String apiKey) {

        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        Call<Headlines> call;
        if (!etQuery.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().getSpecifiedData(query, apiKey);
        } else {
            call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().getHeadLines(country, apiKey);

        }


        call.enqueue(new Callback<Headlines>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Headlines> call, Response<Headlines> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getArticles() != null) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                   // articles.clear();
                    articles = response.body().getArticles();
                    adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), articles);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Headlines> call, Throwable t) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public String getCountry() {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        String country = locale.getCountry();
        return country.toLowerCase();


    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
    public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<Articles> articles;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<Articles> articles) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      final Articles a = articles.get(position);

        String imageUrl = a.getUrlToImage();
        String url = a.getUrl();

           holder.tvTitle.setText(a.getTitle());
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);



        holder.tvSource.setText(a.getSource().getName());
        holder.tvDate.setText(dateTime(a.getPublishedAt()));

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title",a.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("source",a.getSource().getName());
        intent.putExtra("time",dateTime(a.getPublishedAt()));
        intent.putExtra("desc",a.getDescription());
        intent.putExtra("imageUrl",a.getUrlToImage());
        intent.putExtra("url",a.getUrl());
        context.startActivity(intent);
           }
       });

        if (news.favoriteDatabase.favoriteDao().isFavorite(articles.get(position).getId())==1)
        holder.bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);
        else
            holder.bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_border_24);


        holder.bookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FavoriteList favoriteList = new FavoriteList();
                int id = articles.get(position).getId();
                String source = articles.get(position).getSource().getName();
                String author = articles.get(position).getAuthor();
                String publishedAt = articles.get(position).getPublishedAt();
                String description = articles.get(position).getDescription();
                String title = articles.get(position).getTitle();
                String url = articles.get(position).getUrl();
                String urlToImage = articles.get(position).getUrlToImage();
                 favoriteList.setId(id);
                favoriteList.setAuthor(author);
                favoriteList.setDescription(description);
                favoriteList.setSource(source);
                favoriteList.setPublishedAt(publishedAt);
                favoriteList.setTitle(title);
                favoriteList.setUrl(url);
                favoriteList.setUrlToImage(urlToImage);
                favoriteList.setPublishedAt(dateTime(articles.get(position).getPublishedAt()));

                if (news.favoriteDatabase.favoriteDao().isFavorite(id)!=1){
                    holder.bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark);
                    news.favoriteDatabase.favoriteDao().addData(favoriteList);

                }else {    
                    holder.bookmark.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_border_24);
                    news.favoriteDatabase.favoriteDao().delete(favoriteList);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle, tvSource, tvDate;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageButton bookmark;
        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            tvSource = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSource);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            bookmark = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favrr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: so does it behaves same when you restart the application?

Comment: yes it sometimes shows all rows favorites and somwtimes not...im not getting why is it behaving like that..can you help @kelvin

Comment: I mean to say when you open the activity for the first time does it selects all rows as fav/bookmarked?

Comment: when i first install app in device it shows all blank...then i add one to favorites it glows then i visit second tab it displays also but when i revisit first tab it glows allrows favorites @kelvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to debug:

1. Add 2-3 items as Favs.
2. Restart the Application.
   Check if it shows those items as fav after restarting application .

also add logs to those if conditions where you are changing the drawables.

After looking at your JSON it looks like id is what creating problems. Id is null for all your json items so when fav. one it shows fav. to all.

Solution : Use another field to check if the data is added to fav.list

Delete will not work either
Try

```
@Query("DELETE FROM favoritelist WHERE title = :title")
void deleteByUserId(String title);
```

To delete item

Also https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

check this library to debug your database

Comment: i used this library....now on app install..it shows blank at first...in browser it is storing one one favorite (that is one row) i tried adding another as favorites but is not storing 2 favorites in db...it replaces the previous with new one

Comment: i did thid ==> autogenerate true than it shows rows successfully in db but still there is problem in glowing favorite icon

Comment: can you add json to your Question I am trying to recreate your project

Comment: i change from id to title...it works fine with showing the favorite...problem is  delete the favorite...when i unselect the favorite  it glows off that moment ...when i revists the tab ..it glows ...it creating problem with dlete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221850/discussion-between-kelvin-and-iron-man).

Comment: need help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424508/push-notification-enable-and-disable-by-using-switch