# push notification enable and disable by using switch

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase push notification(FCM).. and I want to enable and disable notifications using a switch button.

For that I have shared preferences to enable and disable notifications but it seems my logic is not at all working.

It doesn't make any difference if the switch is turn on or off. I am still receiving notifications.

I need help thanks.

activity:--

```
  val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myname", MODE_PRIVATE)

    simpleSwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("SWITCH_PARTIDOS_STATE", false))

    simpleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("SWITCH_PARTIDOS_STATE", isChecked).commit()
        if (isChecked) {
           // FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Partidos")

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Activado Correctamente",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
          //  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("Partidos")
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Desactivado Correctamente",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        PreferenceHelper.prefernceHelperInstace.setBoolean(applicationContext, Constants.MessageNotificationKeys.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION, true);

    })
```

firebasemessagingservice:---

```
  override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    if (PreferenceHelper.prefernceHelperInstace.getBoolean(getApplicationContext(),
            Constants.MessageNotificationKeys.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION, true)
    ) {
        Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.notification?.body)
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val channelId = "Default"
        val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification()?.getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification()?.getBody()).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification()?.getBody()))

        val manager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager?
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Default channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            manager!!.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        manager!!.notify(0, builder.build())
    }
    else {
        Log.e("TAG", "ReactFireBaseMessagingService: Notifications Are Disabled by User");

    }

}
```

preferencehelper:--

```
class PreferenceHelper private constructor() {
fun setBoolean(appContext: Context?, key: String?, value: Boolean?) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext).edit()
        .putBoolean(key, value!!).apply()
}

fun getBoolean(
    appContext: Context?, key: String?,
    defaultValue: Boolean?
): Boolean {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)
        .getBoolean(key, defaultValue!!)
}

fun getInteger(appContext: Context?, key: String?, defaultValue: Int): Int {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)
        .getInt(key, defaultValue)
}


companion object {
    val prefernceHelperInstace = PreferenceHelper()
}
```

}

using the method of topic(need help ):---------

```
     val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myname", MODE_PRIVATE)

    simpleSwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("SWITCH_STATE", false))

    simpleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("SWITCH_STATE", isChecked).commit()
        if (isChecked) {
            // FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Partidos")
  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("main_notification");
         

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "enabled notification",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("main_notification");
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "disabled notification",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    })
```

The problem of this code is it doesn't worked at first(it receives notification at on off both) after switching on off (switching buttons) it works(when on receives notification and off doesn't receive).

Comment: I think if you need control over push notifications manually then you should create a topic on Firebase console and subscribe to it. The reason behind that is Firebase handles default notifications on separate channel/topic internally that you can't control manually via app.

Comment: @JeelVankhede so do i need to make changes in onmessagereceived for topic?

Comment: No, service will work as it is without any conditional checks. All you need is to opt-in/opt-out from topic based on user's preference changes.

Comment: i dont get it when you say `opt-in/opt-out`?

Comment: You can Un/Subscribe to topic once you launch the app/whatever scenario best fits you based on preference value that you're storing using `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: okay @JeelVankhede but what i used above using shared prefernce will it not work?

Comment: @IRONMAN AFAIK, that should have worked, but if it's not working then using Topics is the best way to implement the similar behaviour.

Comment: @tronku i edited my question ..i have used the topic but facing problem

Comment: @JeelVankhede  i edited my question ..i have used the topic but facing problem

Comment: @JeelVankhede it doesnt worked at first ...when i try switching button  then it works

Comment: @JeelVankhede is there any other way other than subcribetoTopic?

Comment: You'll need to put same condition on un/subscribe after `simpleSwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("SWITCH_STATE", false))` to make it work when activity is open for the first time without any manual click event.

Comment: need help in new question @JeelVankhede https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436252/check-value-exists-or-not-using-encryptedsharedpreferences-android

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseMessagingService` runs in the background even when the app's not in the foreground so you won't be able to get the preferences using `applicationContext`.
You should use Topic messaging -  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Use this in your switch's change listener:

To enable push notifications -

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your_topic");
```

To disable push notifications -

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("your_topic");
```

This way you will notify Firebase that you don't want to get notifications about a particular topic.

Comment: what if i dont want to use `subscribeToTopic` i mean because im not sending topic wise  my target `app` --> package im selecting as target while sending notifications...

Comment: Alright, please try to access preferences by using `com.mypackage.app.getApplicationContext()` in the `appContext` param

Comment: error at applicationContext code-- `com.example.nameofapp.applicationContext`

Comment: i edited my question ..i have used the topic but facing problem

Comment: is there any other way other than subcribetoTopic?

Comment: Can you share how you are using topics in the FCM dashboard?