# check value exists or not using EncryptedSharedPreferences android

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, logout, encrypted-shared-preference

I use the EncryptedSharedPreferences to store value while login...i want to change text in navigation drawer of home activity

so when user is loggedin it will show `logout` else it will show `login` navigation drawer

Loginactivity:--------

```
 sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        "secret_shared_prefs",
        masterKeyAlias,
        baseContext,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    ) as EncryptedSharedPreferences
```

while login im doing this

```
  val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
   editor.putString("EmailId", edtEmailId)
   editor.putString("password", edtPassword)
     editor.apply()
```

checking in Homeactivity:---------

```
        val menu: Menu = bind.navRightView.getMenu()

    val nav_connection: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_login)

   val sharedPreference =
            applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("secret_shared_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val value: String = sharedPreference.getString("EmailId", null).toString()

    if(!sharedPreference.contains(value))
    {
        nav_connection.title = "Loginn"

    }
    else{
        nav_connection.title = "Logout"

    }
```

well output of this code is always having a title as loginn that means it detecting value as null
need help for EncryptedSharedPreferences thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use actual `value` in the contains method, contains method expect key to be passed and not value as parameter. Check out reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#contains(java.lang.String)

Comment: You should try with `sharedPreference.contains('EmailId')`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede  need help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596957/onpaymentfailure-not-getting-called-in-razorpay

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the values but not saving them to `SharedPreferences`.
You should be using `commit()` or `apply()`.

Do this:

```kotlin
   val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
   editor.putString("EmailId", edtEmailId)
   editor.putString("password", edtPassword)
   editor.apply() // Important
```

I also see that you are calling

```kotlin
val sharedPreference = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("secret_shared_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`
```

which gives you the normal `SharedPreference`, I guess.
You should be using:

```kotlin
val sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        "secret_shared_prefs",
        masterKeyAlias,
        baseContext,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    ) as EncryptedSharedPreferences
```

Then check if the email address is empty or not.

```kotlin
if(!sharedPreference.contains("EmailId") 
    nav_connection.title = "Loginn"
else 
    nav_connection.title = "Logout"
```

Comment: hi sorry i forgot add that in question but i have already aplied that but not working

Comment: need help as above code is not working with editor.apply() also

Comment: but i have done in loginactivity ...but need to check in homeactivity

Comment: Initialize the variable `sharedPreference` like above in HomeActivity & use `getString()`

Comment: got any solution ??

Comment: im getting null

Comment: i debug this     if(!sharedPreference.contains(value))
 got null in value